# How do i draw interactive map on HTML5 canvas with geoJSON coordinates (or data)

Tags: html, canvas, dictionary, geojson

I am working on a dashboard-like web application similar to [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), where different sets of data are displayed in different formats including maps.

The requirements are that the map should have click-able regions so as to load data specific to that region and the regions should have hover effects, [much like this one](http://download.ysatech.com/HTML5_Interactive_Map/InteractiveMapPoint.aspx) . I do not want to use google maps API but I am open to libraries.

Now, i have the map data in geoJSON (see snippet below) which brings me to my problem, how do I draw the map in HTML5 canvas using the geoJSON data? I know how general the question is that's because i really have no clue where to start. So i pretty much need someone to hold my hand and show me the way. Please keep your answers as detailed as possible. Thanks.

```
    {
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "features": [{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, 
    "properties": { "OBJECTID_1": 29, "OBJECTID": 29, "COUNTY_NAM": "BARINGO", "COUNTY_COD": 30, "Shape_Leng": 5.81571392065, "Shape_Area": 0.88451236881 }, 
    "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 36.028686523000033, 1.276123047000056 ], [ 36.036499023000033, 1.263916016000053 ], [ 36.039306641000053, 1.259887695000032 ],............[ 36.028686523000033, 1.276123047000056 ] ] ] } }
    ]
    }
```

My research has led me to libraries such as openlayers, leaflet and d3. These are all great but come with a significant learning curve. I have nothing against learning but i'd like the simplest solution to finish the project.

Comment: Okay, you need to define the project more closely. Do you want this map to be draggable and zoomable? Do you want it to be compatible with what browsers? The easiest way to do it from scratch would be to create an SVG element in your html and fill it with lines from your geoJSON data, and attach onHover/onClick events - using jQuery to help perhaps. But that has compatibility problems, which is what libs like D3 and OpenLayers give you. StackOverflow isn't for detailed handholding which ends up doing your job for you.

Comment: I should'nt have used the phrase "hold my hand" its not what i'm looking for, just a point in the right direction, which your latest comment has accomplished partly. The map does not need zoomability, only clickable regions that trigger loading of new content. Think of the map as a navigation of sorts. As for browser compatability, that's not much of a concern as the application is not for public use, its a dashboard for a company(the client). So will the geoJSON need to be converted to svg paths or are the coordinates usable as they are?

Comment: Find some basic tutorials on SVG in browsers. Have a play, then come back and ask some more questions. You'll figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You need a javascript mapping package. Open source choices include openlayers and leaflet. Google will find them for you.

Comment: I have looked at these options, but it seems like overkill. All i want to do is create [something like this](http://download.ysatech.com/HTML5_Interactive_Map/InteractiveMapPath.aspx) but with geoJSON polygon coordinates. Any thought on how i might accomplish that?

Comment: 1. You didn't say you'd done any research. 2. The trouble with "all I want to do" questions is you often end up wanting to do more, and limited tools will limit you. 3. Did you look at d3js.org?

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning my research. See edited question. I am open to using openlayers, leaflet and even d3. I simply want to see if there is an easier solution before i jump into the deep end with these libraries.

Comment: There's also Raphael: http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html - I don't understand how anything could get more simpler than taking your geoJSON data, converting it a bit so it works with a drawing library, and using the drawing library...

Answer (score 0):

Use Smallworld.js for your task.

```
$('.map').smallworld({
    geojson: data
});
```

// OR…

```
Smallworld.defaults.geojson = data;
$('.map').smallworld();
```

See [http://mikefowler.me/smallworld.js][1]